# SCHEME program explanation

Tags: scheme, racket

Studying for a test, and this is a practice problem:

> What does the following Scheme function do? You must explain each block/case of the codes and provide two test cases.
>
> ```lisp
> (define (x lis)
>  (cond
>    ((null? lis) 0)
>    ((not (list? (car lis)))
>     (cond
>       ((eqv? (car lis) 3)(x (cdr lis)))
>       (else (+ 1 (x (cdr lis))))))
>    (else (+ (x (car lis)) (x (cdr lis))))
>  )
> )
> ```

Could someone break down this code?

Comment: That’s a random function — hints: look at where the argument `x` is in relation to parentheses in the body of the lambda (it might have been given a better name); look at what _type_ of thing the lambda returns; look for any special handling of the current element; try to identify the lambda as one of _producer_, _consumer_, or _transformer_, and remember the list handling method: if I can do something to the first element of a list in relation to the remainder of the list, I can manipulate the entire list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I rewrote this code to more readable form (and I also replaced inner `cond` with `if`, meaning of code won't change):

```
(define (x lis)
  (cond
    ((null? lis) 0)
    ((not (list? (car lis)))
     (if
      (eqv? (car lis) 3)
      (x (cdr lis))
      (+ 1 (x (cdr lis)))))
    (else (+ (x (car lis))
             (x (cdr lis))))))
```

And now, I will break this line by line:

- `cond` with three clauses `null?`, `list? (car ...)`, `else` - you're going through given list, doing something with each element
- `((null? lis) 0)`: zero is neutral element for addition, so result of this function will be number and you're summing something
- `((not (list? (car lis)))`: when `car` is "atom"...
- `(eqv? (car lis) 3)`
- ... and it's `3`, call this function with `(cdr lis)` = ignore this element
- ... and it isn't `3`, call this function with `(cdr lis)`, but add `1` to result
- `(+ (x (car lis)) (x (cdr lis)))` else sum result of this function called on `car` and result of this function called on `cdr` (this is common pattern for functions, which work with nested lists, for example `flatten`)

So, what does this function do? It returns *count of elements in given list, that are different from 3*, and given list can be nested.

See examples:

```
> (x '(1 2 3 4 5))
4
```

There's five elements in list, but one is `eqv?` to `3`, so you don't count it.

```
> (x '(3 3 3))
0
```

Three elements in list, but every is `eqv?` to `3`, so you skip them all.

```
> (x '(1 2 (3 4) (5 6 (7))))
6
```

Seven elements in this nested list, but one is `eqv?` to `3`, so you count only six.